# I am facing an issue to Google Sign in IN IOS 13.1

Tags: swift, ios13

### At the time for calling this (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()) is Showing error ("reason: 'presentingViewController must be set.')

Full Error below

> 2019-10-25 12:12:31.060880+0530[7575:70886] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'presentingViewController must be set.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa02c +[NSException raise:format:]
>    + 188
>       3   LiveVideo                           0x000000010b2bb7e4 -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:]
>    + 123
>       4   LiveVideo                           0x000000010b2bb1b2 -[GIDSignIn signIn] + 64
>       5   LiveVideo                           0x000000010b1c9390 $s9LiveVideo21ProfileViewControllerC12googleSignUpyyypF + 272
>       6   LiveVideo                           0x000000010b1c9400 $s9LiveVideo21ProfileViewControllerC12googleSignUpyyypFTo + 80
>       7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4757a082 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
>    + 83
>       8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f608e5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
>    + 223
>       9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f60c2f -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
>    + 398
>       10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f5fb8e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
>    + 481
>       11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff475b4a31 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
>    + 2604
>       12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff475b6338 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
>    + 4596
>       13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47591693 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
>    + 356
>       14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47611e5a __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 6847
>       15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47614920 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5980
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0d271 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_ + 17
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0d19c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0c974 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0767f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b06e66 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
>       21  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38346bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
>       22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47578dd0 UIApplicationMain + 1621
>       23  LiveVideo                           0x000000010b2b25ab main + 75
>       24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff516ecd29 start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 7):

## Please add the time of assigning Delegate.

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = self